# Associative property needed?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $a,b,c$ be real numbers. It is $a \cdot b \cdot c = b \cdot a \cdot c$

This seems pretty basic, but I am unsure, is the associative property needed, to prove this?

Cheers

Comment: Without the associative property, neither side of the equation you've written is properly defined, unless there is a convention that you have failed to mention as to the order in which the operations are to be carried out.

Comment: Thank you very much, Dave.

Comment: @Dave I don't think so. Operators are usually evaluated from left to right if no other rules apply. So $a\cdot b\cdot c$ is defined as $(a\cdot b)\cdot c$.

Comment: miracle173, so for a * b * c = b * a * c I would only need the commutative property but for a * b * c = a * c * b I would also need the associative property?